# Debugging hold mode form doesn't open

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-debugging, static-classes

I have a class library with a public static class "Zuordnung" with some inforamtion needed in my application Mainform.

```
namespace IIB1_UE1_Gruppe25
{
    public static class Zuordnung
    {
        public static Dictionary<String, Double> dieNutzungsListe = new Dictionary<String, double>()
        {
            {"Bitte auswählen", 0},
            {"Wohnung", 50},
            {"Büro", 60.1}

        };


        public static BindingList<Raum> dieRaumListe = new BindingList<Raum>()
        {
            new Raum(){RaumNummer = "Büro 112", RaumFlaeche = 30.5, Raumfeuerloescher = null, Raumnutzungsart = null},
            new Raum(){RaumNummer = "Wohnzimmer 1", RaumFlaeche = 50, Raumfeuerloescher = null, Raumnutzungsart = null},
            new Raum(){RaumNummer = "Kantine", RaumFlaeche = 200.22, Raumfeuerloescher = null, Raumnutzungsart = null},
        };
```

Code snippet of class Raum

```
public class Raum
{
    public String RaumNummer { get; set; }      
    public double RaumFlaeche { get; set; }
    public Nutzungsart Raumnutzungsart { get; set; }
    public List<Feuerloescher> Raumfeuerloescher { get; set; }

    public Raum() { }

    public Raum(String _RaumNummer, double _RaumFlaeche)
    {
        RaumNummer = _RaumNummer;
        RaumFlaeche = _RaumFlaeche;
        Raumnutzungsart = null;
        Raumfeuerloescher = null;
    }
}
```

I've a constructor for my mainform with two needed attributes

```
public partial class Hauptfenster : Form
{
    private BindingList<Raum> Raeume;
    private Dictionary<String, Double> Nutzung;

    public Hauptfenster(BindingList<Raum> _dieRaumliste, Dictionary<String,Double> _dieNutzungsliste )
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Raeume = _dieRaumliste;
        this.Nutzung = _dieNutzungsliste;

        listBoxRaum.DataSource = Raeume;
        listBoxRaum.DisplayMember = "RaumNummer";     
    }
```

Code snippet from class Program

```
static class Program
{
    private static BindingList<Raum> meineRaueme = new BindingList<Raum>();
        /// <summary>
        /// Der Haupteinstiegspunkt für die Anwendung.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Hauptfenster(Zuordnung.dieRaumListe, Zuordnung.dieNutzungsListe));
        }
```

The application did run without problems when the constructor was without attributes. Now the debugging switch to hold mode without showing any failures, just the sentence that there is no code to run.

Any help is highly appreciated.
Sorry for bad english ^^

Comment: `Now the debubbuging switch to hold mode without showing any failures` I am not sure what that sentence means.

Comment: When i start the debugging normaly the form i built starts and i can check the application, but know the debugging does nothing.

Comment: @Metehan Yalcin, Maybe a screen shot would be better for us to really understand this issue, as you said debugging does nothing, do you add a breakpoint to test it?